# Are workspace-ergonomics questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Are questions about configuration of a workspace for ergonomic factors on-topic here?  If so, are they limited to physical factors (e.g. the [question about focus in open seating](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/778/325)), or does it include software factors?

For example, would a question about reducing eyestrain when working at a computer, taking into account OS settings, altering one's own space, and having to play well with those sitting nearby (e.g. no blocking the windows), be on-topic?

(Background: I followed a link here from Google+ yesterday.  I've reviewed the questions on the front page of both main and meta.  Since the FAQ isn't yet customized for this site, that's everything I know about what this site is about.)

Comment: Do you have an existing question in mind?

Comment: @YannisRizos, the eyestrain question I outlined.  (A full treatment would describe the problem, current setting, and what I'm allowed and forbidden to change in the environment.)

Comment: Oh, yes, I meant a question that was already asked on the site. It's not really easy to argue hypotheticals.

Comment: @YannisRizos, I linked the qeustion that prompted my question.  I haven't seen any ergonomics questions, but they seem in the same ballpark as a question about making open seating suck less, but the site is young and scope isn't clear yet so I didn't want to just ask it.  As I said, I'm new here and I haven't seen a lot of info about what's on/off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ask your question well, and it'll be used to help define the site.

I think there's no reason that this question couldn't be on topic here if asked properly. The needle you're trying to thread is trying to make the question not too broad nor too specific, while also phrasing it in such a way that doesn't invite "bad subjective" answers.

Comment: Done: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/945/how-do-i-make-my-workplace-easier-on-my-eyes

Answer (score 4):

[John N](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/158/16) answered it well if a bit consisely.

Avoid asking for recommendations.  A good question about a type of product will probably end up with several recommendations anyway.  But when you ask for them directly it opens the door for, ohh I know of another one ill pile on too, answers.

For your question about Eyestrain, I think if you include the problem you are having, and the goal you would like to reach, the question should be on topic.

When asking questions try to [Rubber Duck](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html) the question.  This will get you the best answers to help you, and reduce your likelihood of there being a problem with your question.